# Add View All link to show all products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am getting a problem to add View All button to show all products in Category page in the toolbar. How will I do this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to rewrite 1 plugin and 1 preference to make this happens. There is no default 'View All' available in the menu like M1.

Ok, here we go.

> app/code/Stackoverflow/Catalog/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2017 Toan Nguyen. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
  -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenu" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenuViewAll" type="Stackoverflow\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" />
    </type>
</config>
```

You will need to copy this file: `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu` to `Stackoverflow\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu`, because we are going to disable the M2 default plugin to use our new one, this is how we override a plugin.

> app/code/Stackoverflow/Catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu

```
/**
 * Convert category to array
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $currentCategory
 *
 * @return array
 */
private function getCategoryAsArray($category, $currentCategory)
{
    return [
        'name' => $category->getName(),
        'id' => 'category-node-' . $category->getId(),
        'url' => $this->catalogCategory->getCategoryUrl($category),
        'has_active' => in_array((string)$category->getId(), explode('/', $currentCategory->getPath()), true),
        'is_active' => $category->getId() == $currentCategory->getId(),
        'is_view_all' => $this->isDisplayViewAllLink($category)
    ];
}
```

You will need to add a new key into this method, e.g is_view_all, in my situation, I only need to display view all link for specified categories. That is why you see `$this->isDisplayViewAllLink($category)`

The next step, we will need to create a preference for this class `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`

You will override this method `_addSubMenu()` to something like this

```
/**
 * Add sub menu HTML code for current menu item
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child
 * @param string                            $childLevel
 * @param string                            $childrenWrapClass
 * @param int                               $limit
 *
 * @return string HTML code
 */
protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
{
    $html = '';
    if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
        return $html;
    }

    $colStops = null;
    if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
        $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
    }

    $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' submenu">';
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
    if ((int)$childLevel === 0 && $child->getDataByKey('is_view_all')) {
        $html .=     '<li class="level'. ((int)$childLevel + 1) .' view-all">';
        $html .=         '<a class="level'. ((int)$childLevel + 1) .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'?product_list_limit=all">';
        $html .=             __('View All');
        $html .=         '</a>';
        $html .=     '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Remember to add `(int)$childLevel === 0` to ensure "View All" links will be added to level0 menu.

Hope it helps :)

## UPDATED

I misunderstood the op question. If you want to add kind of 'View All' link to the product list page. You will need to override this template

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/pager.phtml

```
    <?php if ($block->getShowAmounts()): ?>
    <p class="toolbar-amount">
        <span class="toolbar-number">
        <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items %1 to %2 of %3 total', $block->getFirstNum(), $block->getLastNum(), $block->getTotalNum()) ?>
        <?php elseif ($block->getTotalNum() == 1): ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 Item', $block->getTotalNum()) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 Item(s)', $block->getTotalNum()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
        <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLimitUrl($block->getTotalNum()) ?>"><?php echo __('View All');  ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: But I need to show all products in the category page.

Comment: @AmritPalSingh Check my updated answer, lol

Comment: I'm getting an error like this: "Unused private method getCategoryAsArray()"